# Problems with showing my screens and functions to work in javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get my screens and functions to work correctly. I am now stuck at the start page of my website/game.
I have two problems:

It seems that my click events don't work, nothing happens when I press my start buttons. After I've pressed them I then want the actual game to show up which is my "game_start".

After I press my start buttons, I want the "game_start" id screen to be hidden and the actual "game" id screen to show up.

Thankful for the help //rookie

```js
window.addEventListener("load", start);

function startscreen() {
  //unhide screens
  document.querySelector("#game_start").classList.remove("hidden");

  //EventListeners
  document.querySelector("#start_button").addEventListener("click", StartGame);
  document.querySelector("#start_button_2").addEventListener("click", StartGame);
}

function StartGame() {
  console.log("StartGame");
  //hide screens
  document.querySelector("game_start").classList.add("hidden");
  //add screens
  document.querySelector("#game").classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```html
<div id="game_start" class="hidden">
  <img src="Assets copy.SVG/HOMESCREEN.svg" alt="Start">
  <div id="start_button" alt="start">
    <span class="blink"><img src="Assets copy.SVG/START.GREEN.svg"></span></a>
  </div>
  <div id="start_button_2" alt="start">
    <img src="Assets copy.SVG/START.GREY.svg"></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="game" class="hidden">
  <div id="game_consol"> <img src="Assets copy.SVG/GAME_CONSOL.svg" alt="GameConsol"></div>
  <div id="game_foreground"> <img src="Assets copy.SVG/STARS.svg" alt="GameForeground"></div>
  <div id="game_background"> <img src="Assets copy.SVG/BACKGROUND.svg" alt="GameBackground"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: when you say "screen" you are actually talking about divs?

Comment: little known fact: if your elements have `id` attributes, _they already exist as variables on the JS side_ and you don't need to queryselect for them. A `<div id="game_background">` has a matched JS variable called `game_background` automatically allocated. Even if they have normally illegal name, they will exist on the `window` object and you can access them as properly. E.g. `<div id="1234">` can be found on `window["1234"]`.

Comment: `window.addEventListener("load", start)` there is no `start` function here

Comment: Thank you guys, very much. When I say screens, I mean my divs inside my "screen". I got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

I assume on `window` `load` you want to invoke `startscreen`. Then remove the `game_start` `div` and display the `game` `div` when button `start_button` is clicked right?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", startscreen);

function startscreen() {
  //unhide screens
  document.querySelector("#game_start").classList.remove("hidden");

  //EventListeners
  document.querySelector("#start_button").addEventListener("click", StartGame);
  document.querySelector("#start_button_2").addEventListener("click", StartGame);
}

function StartGame() {
  console.log("StartGame");
  //hide screens
  document.querySelector("#game_start").classList.add("hidden");
  //add screens
  document.querySelector("#game").classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="game_start" class="hidden">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/100/100" alt="Start">
  <div id="start_button" alt="start">
    <span class="blink"><img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100"></span></a>
  </div>
  <div id="start_button_2" alt="start">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/100/100"></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="game" class="hidden">
  <div id="game_consol"> <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="GameConsol"></div>
  <div id="game_foreground"> <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/100/100" alt="GameForeground"></div>
  <div id="game_background"> <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="GameBackground"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

addEventListener("load", start);
but I dont seen any start function in your code!!!

```
 window.addEventListener("load", startscreen());
```

and of course dont forget **StartGame** call your function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay more attention to details. In my code you can check the comments for the errors.

In javascript code:

```
// First Error: Where is the function "start" ?
//    window.addEventListener("load", start);
```

and

```
// Second Error: Your ID selector need `#` before the name.
//    document.querySelector("game_start").classList.add("hidden");
```

In html code you closed two link (`a` TAG) but it never opened.

```js
// First Error: Where is the function "start" ?
//    window.addEventListener("load", start);
window.addEventListener("load", startscreen);

function startscreen() {
  //unhide screens
  document.querySelector("#game_start").classList.remove("hidden");

  //EventListeners
  document.querySelector("#start_button").addEventListener("click", StartGame);
  document.querySelector("#start_button_2").addEventListener("click", StartGame);
}

function StartGame() {
  console.log("StartGame");
  
  // Second Error: Your ID selector need # before the name.
  //     document.querySelector("game_start").classList.add("hidden");
  
  //hide screens
  document.querySelector("#game_start").classList.add("hidden");
  //add screens
  document.querySelector("#game").classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="game_start" class="hidden">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50/0055FF/fff?text=HEADER" alt="Start">
  <div id="start_button" alt="start">
    <span class="blink"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50/FF00FF/fff?text=buttton+1"></span><!--Where is the open ? </a> -->
  </div>
  <div id="start_button_2" alt="start">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50/FF0000/fff?text=button+2"><!--Where is the open ? </a> -->
  </div>
</div>

<div id="game" class="hidden">
  <div id="game_consol"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50/FF5500/fff?text=Game+Header" alt="GameConsol"></div>
  <div id="game_foreground"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50/FF0055/fff?text=Foreground" alt="GameForeground"></div>
  <div id="game_background"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50/55FF55/fff?text=Background" alt="GameBackground"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("load", startscreen);

function startscreen() {
  //unhide screens
  document.querySelector("#game_start").classList.remove("hidden");

  //EventListeners
  document.querySelector("#start_button").addEventListener("click", StartGame);
  document.querySelector("#start_button_2").addEventListener("click", StartGame);
}

function StartGame() {
  console.log("StartGame");
  //hide screens
  document.querySelector("#game_start").classList.add("hidden");
  //add screens
  document.querySelector("#game").classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```css
#start_button, #start_button_2{
 cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="game_start" class="hidden">
  <img src="Assets copy.SVG/HOMESCREEN.svg" alt="Start">
  <div id="start_button">
    <span class="blink"><img alt="start" src="Assets copy.SVG/START.GREEN.svg"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="start_button_2">
    <img alt="start2" src="Assets copy.SVG/START.GREY.svg">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="game" class="hidden">
  <div id="game_consol"> <img src="Assets copy.SVG/GAME_CONSOL.svg" alt="GameConsol"></div>
  <div id="game_foreground"> <img src="Assets copy.SVG/STARS.svg" alt="GameForeground"></div>
  <div id="game_background"> <img src="Assets copy.SVG/BACKGROUND.svg" alt="GameBackground"></div>
</div>
```

Change startscreen in the `window.addEventListener("load", startscreen);` and remove the random `<a/>`'s.

Then the `document.querySelector("game_start").classList.add("hidden");` needs to have the **#** in it like this `document.querySelector("#game_start").classList.add("hidden");`